# OkHttp3 Cookie Persistent

Tags: cookies, okhttp

```
public void add(HttpUrl url, Cookie cookie) {
    String name = getCookieToken(cookie);

    //将cookies缓存到内存中 如果缓存过期 就重置此cookie
    if (!cookie.persistent()) {
        if (!cookies.containsKey(url.host())) {
            cookies.put(url.host(), new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Cookie>());
        }
        cookies.get(url.host()).put(name, cookie);
    } else {
        if (cookies.containsKey(url.host())) {
            cookies.get(url.host()).remove(name);
        }
    }

    LogUtil.e("Cookie：" + cookies.get(url.host()).keySet().toString());
    //讲cookies持久化到本地
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsWriter = cookiePrefs.edit();
    prefsWriter.putString(url.host(), TextUtils.join(",", cookies.get(url.host()).keySet()));
    prefsWriter.putString(name, encodeCookie(new SerializableOkHttpCookies(cookie)));
    prefsWriter.apply();
}

public List<Cookie> get(HttpUrl url) {
    ArrayList<Cookie> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cookies.containsKey(url.host()))
        ret.addAll(cookies.get(url.host()).values());
    return ret;
}
```

When I used okhttp3 to create a cookie persistence, there was an exception:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Set java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()' on a null object reference
```

Many people say that it is because of the JDK1.8 version of the concurrenthashmap return value, but I do not know how to solve.My JDK version is 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Your add method has two non null safe calls to the cookies Map.  I think just edit these two lines to use the safe get method or use null checks.

From:

```
LogUtil.e("Cookie：" + cookies.get(url.host()).keySet().toString());
```

To:

```
if (cookies.containsKey(url.host())) 
  LogUtil.e("Cookie：" + cookies.get(url.host()).keySet().toString());
```

and this line also

```
prefsWriter.putString(url.host(), TextUtils.join(",", cookies.get(url.host()).keySet()));
```